# Can AWS SnowballEdge Device convert file format

Tags: amazon-web-services

We have old customized files in S3bucket, that need to be converted to a readable new format. The Application to convert files is in our datacentre, we are looking for the cheapest option to convert the files and reload it back to S3 bucket.

I want to know if it is possible to install an application to convert files format on the Snowball Edge device or EC2, please?
Thanks

Comment: Please edit your question to add more details of your use-case. For example, what type of conversion do you wish to perform? Will it be done to _all_ files added to the Snowball? Why do you wish to convert the data on the Snowball instead of doing it after an upload to S3?

Answer (score 2):

You cannot "install an application" on a Snowball device.

However, **Snowball Edge supports local Lambda functions**. I think that you can trigger a Lambda function when an object is added to Snowball Edge, and then you can write code for that Lambda function to do things like processing or converting the new file.

See: [Using AWS Lambda with an AWS Snowball Edge - AWS Snowball Edge Developer Guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/snowball/latest/developer-guide/using-lambda.html)

Comment: It is hard to answer this without understand your actual use-case. Feel free to edit your question to explain what you are actually wanting to achieve (rather than 'how').